# Gradle build.gradle code style

Tags: coding-style, gradle

**Is there code style for Gradle `build.gradle` files?**

Of course for groovy pieces Groovy rules could apply,
but for Gradle DSL is there any conventions?

Like [putting plugin configuration right after `apply`](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/style)

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "com.example.MainClass"
```

For Maven I usually used [POM Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Quick_Overview), but putting `<!-- Build Settings -->` as the last section.

As `build.gradle` can grow quite long for some project, it would be nice to have standard structure for references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there's no such specification. It's totally flexible, but good idea is to have a common set rules among the people to work with. I try to follow the rules below

- buildScript
- apply all plugins
- configure the plugins
- repositories
- dependencies
- other

Comment: It's also good practice to split up large build scripts into multiple smaller ones (leveraging `apply from:`).

Answer (score 4):

> As build.gradle can grow quite long for some project, it would be nice to have standard structure for references.

In addition to following a consistent order as suggested by Opal (*), it's also good practice to split up large build scripts into multiple smaller ones. For example you could have `gradle/dependencies.gradle`, `gradle/publishing.gradle`, `gradle/integrationTest.gradle`, etc., all of which are included into `build.gradle` using `apply from:`. In multi-project builds, use a separate build script for each subproject.

(*) My general guideline here is to order declarations by their level of abstraction, with the most abstract declarations coming first, and task declarations coming last.